# Why can't I use some $.post retrieved data as a String?

Tags: jquery, string, post

I'm new on jquery and PHP and now I'm facing a simple but anoying problem.. I've tried to send and retrieve some data using $post, but now my data can't be used as a String to conclude an "if"..

```
$.post($("#formRegister").attr('action'), data).done(
    function( data ) {
        clearInputs();
        var stringData = data.toString(); 
        if(stringData == "Cadastro Efetuado com Sucesso.") {
            var corMsg = "success"
        } else {
            var corMsg = "danger"
        }
        var msgCadastro = '<div class="panel panel-'+corMsg+' text-center" id="msgCadastro"  ><div class="panel-heading">'+data+'</div></div>';
        $("#msgCadastro").remove();
        $("#formRegister").append(msgCadastro);
    }
);
```

PHP:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query1) == 0) {
    $msg =  'Código Inválido.';
} else {
    $query = "UPDATE GlobalTable SET Login = '$login', Password = '$password' Where ValidationCode = '$validationCode'";
    mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    $msg =  'Cadastro Efetuado com Sucesso.';
}
echo $msg;
```

Why ins't working?

Comment: looks like it's already a string. remove the `.toString()` part

Comment: Show your php code also I'm guessing $.trim

Comment: Maybe you were not setting the right headers on the data from the post to whatever you intended. I guess string is the default and you would have to set a data type for text/json if that was what you intended to send.

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` show?

Comment: What does _Why ins't working?_ really mean? any errors?